# Toggle class on :focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggleclass, closest

I'm using a plugin, and am unable to simply adjust the order of the labels and inputs on a form. I'm trying to toggle a class on the label (`.gfield_label`) when an input within `.ginput_container` is focused. Any ideas as to why the following isn't being executed?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    $('.ginput_container input[type="text"], .ginput_container input[type="email"], .ginput_container textarea').focus(function(){
        $(this).closest('.ginput_container').prev('.gfield_label').toggleClass('neat');
    })
});
```

HTML is as follows:

```
<label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_5'>How can we help you today?</label>
<div class='ginput_container'><textarea name='input_5' id='input_1_5' class='textarea medium' tabindex='5'   rows='10' cols='50'></textarea></div>
```

Comment: Without seeing the HTML - no. You're missing a class selector on your second `ginput` tho. Does your console have any errors?

Comment: If you open up developer tools in your browser. Is the console saying anything? As in outputting any errors?

Comment: You forgot a dot before the second classname

Comment: Thanks for catching that @tymeJV, no errors in the console

Comment: This is working fine for me in jsfiddle, but of course it does not remove `.neat` from the label when the box loses focus, because you are not listening to the `blur` event

Comment: This seems to work fine. Maybe the textarea does not exist when the focus event is being bound? If that's the case, look into using a delegated event.